I wan to make app's text fonts irrespective to the display size changes in phone's display settings . I've used the following code but doesn't work
MaterialApp(
title: 'Bottle App',
          builder: (context, child) {
            return MediaQuery(
              data: MediaQuery.of(context)
                  .copyWith(textScaler: TextScaler.linear(1.0)),
              child: child!,
            );
          },
          
          home: isUserInfoSaved ? StartInputScreen() : SignUpScreen()
          );

Whatever the display size setting of phone is (xs,s,l) i want app's sizes to be same

This question is similar to: How to make Flutter app font size independent from device settings?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, you don't.  People set the display size because they have physical problems making them unable to see the text when it's too small.  They have a disability.  What you're asking to do is the equivalent of filing the braille off of a sign because you don't like the bumps.  Or removing a ramp for wheelchair users because you prefer stairs.  You're not just failing to build something to help these people, you're actively removing something that's built in.  It's immoral and wrong.
